# Kindle does not show epub book correctly

Tags: kindle, epub

I am trying to read the `.epub` version of [this book](https://archive.org/details/servilestate00belluoft), but when I open it in the kindle, the page numbers and the header of each page (which as you can see from that website correspond alternatively to the title of the book and the title of the section) appear usually around the middle of the text.

For example, I get something like:

> ...
>   nothing like it or approaching it has ever
>   been done or is now xi
>   THE SERVILE STATE
>   being done. I say further, what is of
>   capital importance, that with every step
>   ...

where `xi` corresponds to the number of the page and `THE SERVILE STATE` corresponds to the header of the page. You can see that they appear in the middle of the text. Quite annoying.

Is there something wrong with the file? Is it a problem of my kindle? Can this be fixed?

I have a Kindle 4.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the epub conversions for scans on archive.org tend to be uniformly terrible. (Perhaps they use Abby Finereader's epub conversion tools?) The error you're pointing out is simply the result of scanned text that was never proofed.

You may already know that Project Gutenberg already has an ebook download page for Hillaire Belloc (but not for the title you mentioned).  The PG ebooks are pretty much the gold standard for epub files.  http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/author/2437

If you want a free download and have a large tablet, then I would recommend you use the PDF available from archive.org (No bigger than 6 MB).

Also, I noticed that Amazon has several proofed copies of the Servile State  (Kindle edition) for 99 cents. Judging from reader comments, there aren't complaint about typos, so someone actually proofed the text. [https://www.amazon.com/Servile-State-Hilaire-Belloc-ebook/dp/B003IWZZPW/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003IWZZPW)